# WooCommerce - Variations

Tags: woocommerce, product-variations

I am using WooCommerce in my project and would like to display variations in a similar style like http://www.e-rudy.com/en/products/detail/SN220724R1. They have a tab called "other colors". Is it possible to do that in WooCommerce?

Comment: This are not variations, but a single product with a quantity field as a select field and below specific related products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you will have to add a [custom template](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) for that to be incorporated in the product tabs. In that template you should pull all the variations information corresponding to the main product.

If you don't do it as parent->variations products, you can still link them in the backend and show those in the template. In short, it's doable but you or someone else will have to code that part. It might also be possible to do it with [wp-types views](http://wp-types.com/home/views-create-elegant-displays-for-your-content/), but I have never used it so I can't comment.

Hope that helps to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Like this https://woocamp.com/product/classic-wordpress-shirt/ ?
When you click on the additional sizes, nothing visually happens.  But the size is registered as a variation.  Now, when you select a different color, the image actually changes *and the image switches as well!*

I did that using [WooCommerce Variations and Swatches](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-color-and-image-swatches/)